# Lumen directing all routes of specific group to *

Tags: laravel, lumen, fastroute

I'm developing a website with simple landing page and a few other page such as contacts and news as front end (which uses normal PHP and lumen should be sufficient bythe way) and vuejs as backend. Trying to send all get request from '/admin/' to view('admin'). This is the best I could come up with...

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () use ($router) {

   $router ->get('/{route:.*}/', function () use ($router) { return view('admin'); 

});
```

The problem is all url I do or access, all get request response I get was 404 - not found. Not even any log or anything in lumen log or even in error log apache server. Where did I do wrong?

//using lumen since I need API for vuejs operations.

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash since the default server rewrite rules remove it as well

Comment: Tried that as well but still no luck....even have tried removing both slashes but also the same....

Comment: just to add... Not even errorpage (which should be handled by vuejs) can get pass through.... All error 404 that I get was handled by native lumen.